# How do I breed a tame donkey?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok so I have this town world and I own a horse pasture. I have two donkeys (both tamed) that I would like to breed; however, I have tried feeding them wheat, apples, carrots, etc but they will not even eat it, much less breed. The internet said carrots, but I have already tried that, as stated above. I'm not sure if it is just a glitch or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this info from [here](http://www.minecraft101.net/r/horses.html) on how to tame horses. You can tame a donkey using the same method to tame a horse:

> To tame a horse, approach it with nothing in your hand and right click on it. You will now be riding the horse&emdashfor a second or two, until it throws you off. Try again, and again, until finally you see some red hearts and the horse lets you stay on.
>
> It usually takes 3–5 attempts, but you may be luckier or unluckier than that. You can make the process quicker by feeding the horse first.

In addition:

> Only tamed horses can be bred. To make horses breed, feed them golden apples. They will go into “love mode” and make a baby.

I also found this information from the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse#Breeding), which states that two donkeys can be bred together in the same fashion as breeding horses:

> Breeding two donkeys creates a donkey foal. Since all donkeys have the same texture, the offspring will look exactly like its parents when it is fully grown.

Comment: Yes, they are already tamed and in a fenced in area. I didnt think to try golden apples, the websites I looked on never mentioned them. Thank you

Comment: @Nerdgirl02 If you think this answer is the best answer, you can select it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer, or if you do not, you can wait for more answers